# Selenium Web driver:Want to insert a string value in numeric field

Tags: java, excel, selenium

In my project ,I am reading SSN from Excel file and try to put it in numeric text field.
I use the following code

```
Sheet s;
FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Selenium.xls");
Workbook w= Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
s=w.getSheet(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("TabContainer1_IndividualInfo_txtScocialSecurity_II")).sendKeys(ssn);
String ssn=s.getCell(5,1).getContents();
```

But data is not get inserted into the numeric textfield in browser.

Comment: What is the output of the SSN variable. Does it have the value?

Comment: Assuming you are using Firefox, you probably need to get the latest version of WebDriver.

Comment: Hi Sham ,Output of SSN is a 9 digit number like 123456789.i want to insert this number into text field in browser

Comment: Hi Richard,Is it a versioning problem?How can i resolve it? i am using firefox